# C言語でのソートプログラムが Segmentation fault になる

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_A 10
#define MAX_B 100

void quickSort(int (*E)[MAX_B]);
void q_sort(int *E, int left, int right);

int main(void) {
  int i, j;
  int E[MAX_A][MAX_B];

  for(i = 0; i < MAX_A; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < MAX_B; j++) {
      E[i][j] = rand() % MAX_B;
    }
  }

  quickSort(E);
  for(i = 0; i < MAX_A; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < MAX_B; j++) {
      printf("%d\t", E[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}

void quickSort(int (*E)[MAX_B]) {
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < MAX_B; i++) {
    q_sort(E[i], 0, MAX_B - 1);
  }
}

void q_sort(int* E, int left, int right) {
  int pivot, l_hold, r_hold;

  l_hold = left;
  r_hold = right;
  pivot = E[left];

  while(left < right) {
    while((E[right] >= pivot) && (left < right)) {
      right--;
    }
    if(left != right) {
      E[left] = E[right];
      left++;
    }
    while((E[left] <= pivot) && (left < right)) { 
      left++;
    }
    if(left != right) {
      E[right] = E[left];
      right--;
    }
  }
  E[left] = pivot;
  pivot = left;
  left = l_hold;
  right = r_hold;
  if(left < pivot) {
    q_sort(E, left, pivot-1);
  }
  if(right > pivot) {
    q_sort(E, pivot+1, right);
  }
}
```

C言語でソートを行うプログラムを書いたのですが, Segmentation faultになってしまいます.
どこが間違っているのでしょうか?

---

出力例 : 
1   2   3   3   5   5   6   6   7   9   
0   0   2   2   3   6   6   6   7   9   
0   1   2   2   3   5   7   7   8   9   
1   2   2   2   3   6   7   8   9   9   
0   1   3   4   4   5   7   8   9   9   
0   0   1   1   2   3   3   6   6   6   
3   4   5   5   5   6   6   7   7   9   
0   2   3   4   4   4   4   5   5   7   
1   3   4   4   6   7   8   8   8   9   
0   2   2   4   6   6   6   8   9   9

Comment: 出力例から察するに、10個の要素に対してソート(クイックソート)する処理を100回繰り返したいのだと思われます。
まずは、「10個(`MAX_A`個)の要素をソートする」プログラムを考えてみてはいかがでしょう。
つまり、いきなり2次元の入力を考えるのではなく、1次元配列で始めてみれば間違いにきづけるのではないか、ということです。

Answer (score 3):

とりあえず`quickSort()`の中で`i`が`MAX_B`までループされていますがこれは`MAX_A`までのはずです。

Answer (score 1):

1. コンパイルするときに、-g オプションで、シンボル生成する。
2. デバッガーで、実行形式ファイルを、ロードし、実行させる。
3. コケるときに、どの行で、コケたか、表示される。

   もし、こけたときに、Core Dump してないなら、ulimit -c unlimitedなどとして、Coreダンプするようにしておく。

   なお、qsortは、Cの標準ライブラリにあるので、普通は、自作しないものである。